# Deltalake Python library can't be installed on Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instance for Python 3.7 or 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, delta-lake, amazon-linux-2

I am trying to install `deltalake` Python library (https://github.com/delta-io/delta-rs/tree/main/python) on an Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instance which was launched from `amzn2-ami-hvm-2.0.20210318.0-x86_64-gp2` (`us-east-1` region). It fails as showing below:

```
$ pip3 install deltalake
Collecting deltalake
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement deltalake (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for deltalake
$
```

The current version of this library is `0.4.5`, released on April 5, 2021. I tried the previous version `0.4.4` (`pip3 install deltalake==0.4.4`) which was released on March 23, 2021, but got the same error.

Originally the instance had Python `3.7.9`. Once I got this error, I installed Python `3.8.5` and tried `pip3.8 install deltalake` or `pip3.8 install deltalake==0.4.4`, but get the same error.

How do I find what requirements it is looking for and how to resolve this?

**Update:**

Logs from a verbose mode install attempt (Some hashed characters have been masked with `...` to keep with the character limit on the post):

**Update2:** Replacing the previous logs since those were from a local computer added by mistake. These are the actual logs from the ec2 instance.

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-142-224-101 ~]$  pip3 install -v deltalake
Collecting deltalake
  1 location(s) to search for versions of deltalake:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/deltalake/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/deltalake/
  Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/simple/deltalake/" in the cache
  Returning cached "301 Moved Permanently" response (ignoring date and etag information)
  Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/" in the cache
  Current age based on date: 766
  Freshness lifetime from max-age: 600
  Freshness lifetime from request max-age: 600
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org
  https://pypi.org:443 "GET /simple/deltalake/ HTTP/1.1" 304 0
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/d3/39a...f3b/deltalake-0.1.0-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=2fb...6a140639d462c (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/4d/273...1ad/deltalake-0.1.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=4...6beba06b2d18e93 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/9c/293...40a/deltalake-0.1.0-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=4b4bea219f7ec...39b (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/10/2ec...502/deltalake-0.1.0-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=59a...d21585698213a (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/aa/c0/567...6ff/deltalake-0.1.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=1...137a895405bc8bb (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/10/d2/d23...161/deltalake-0.1.0-cp37-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=e0365a956bc78...48c (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/be/6e0...c82/deltalake-0.1.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=6c38...880f7629e31c (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/21/50c...271/deltalake-0.1.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=cd...0e251e5993911b (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d6/ec/a26...633/deltalake-0.1.0-cp38-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=3cb228d422c4f...a2e (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/53/5e/57f...acc/deltalake-0.1.0-cp39-abi3-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=e60a...d14e9a296673 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5d/14/a10...069/deltalake-0.1.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=b9a0...a49ba9184564 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/19/a49...b2d/deltalake-0.1.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=0d...a47ff4bee906ec (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/33/a72...aec/deltalake-0.1.0-cp39-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=5e266ad419693...ea9 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/33/98a...b21/deltalake-0.1.1-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=e6d...c2b87890632cd (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/94/23/4b0...f5f/deltalake-0.1.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=1...bd700524fc8f7cf (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/bd/9d6...a16/deltalake-0.1.1-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=a392eadbe3f22...35e (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/13/ddf...5ea/deltalake-0.1.1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=4f5...e87a24e1da3b2 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ef/2b/f26...e8b/deltalake-0.1.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=2...b32e79d51c2a1a1 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/58/3b/ab1...0c9/deltalake-0.1.1-cp37-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=998fa6b9dfd4b...251 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/af/50/750...05b/deltalake-0.1.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=f907...59096cb03914 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/ed/1ec...3c3/deltalake-0.1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=7f...1a5c4b02ec0069 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/5a/7d6...6fd/deltalake-0.1.1-cp38-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=e70db3b5f4c76...908 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cd/2e/313...1f8/deltalake-0.1.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=7cc8...235bc782af86 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e7/03/4eb...79c/deltalake-0.1.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=1f...57b87f791b4a7e (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/aa/59/c4b...b01/deltalake-0.1.1-cp39-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=ee41477b9ef01...649 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/df/024...6b6/deltalake-0.1.2-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=5b4...40017b4719eeb (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/33/d3/ce3...27b/deltalake-0.1.2-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=c4e20c89a8f32...39b (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/18/bf/85d...c6f/deltalake-0.1.2-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=368...eaab79b44d9be (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2e/ce/b04...c6d/deltalake-0.1.2-cp37-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=c94316157e23c...adf (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/75/19/20e...f7e/deltalake-0.1.2-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=cc58...862cc8f1cb38 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c3/c7/0bf...da3/deltalake-0.1.2-cp38-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=0a96be37e21a0...d4e (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/91/d6/7f9...a76/deltalake-0.1.2-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=74ff...e81863340815 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/53/a5/24c...3de/deltalake-0.1.2-cp39-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=7e73b89a96053...225 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3f/3f/e84...2a9/deltalake-0.1.3-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=594...58373386804c4 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c0/da/f2f...77f/deltalake-0.1.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=3...d96e0f09c3d0865 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2d/0c/dea...f07/deltalake-0.1.3-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=e8a4e91dd502d...828 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/03/72/511...54c/deltalake-0.1.3-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=1d5...35bdd238d8b21 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/79/22/780...e71/deltalake-0.1.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=d...c34c155c952415e (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c3/dc/88e...975/deltalake-0.1.3-cp37-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=5b4fe2cbb72c6...b0f (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/23/50/83c...c2c/deltalake-0.1.3-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=9d45...ac44f68507e9 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/07/98/69f...a9d/deltalake-0.1.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=60...6505bdab040eca (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c4/5a/d39...089/deltalake-0.1.3-cp38-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=730376ef5bc49...6ae (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/16/1a/4c2...0ee/deltalake-0.1.3-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=e159...b4f92f6ce910 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/e3/217...1bb/deltalake-0.1.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=9e...8aaa96a41ebe2e (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/a1/7a8...a79/deltalake-0.1.3-cp39-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=f3c92981a86b9...2e5 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/65/60a...27c/deltalake-0.1.4-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=d41...f40ca39f69af2 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6b/9b/3ae...139/deltalake-0.1.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=5...4267fc589da04b1 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/56/35/3f9...4e2/deltalake-0.1.4-cp36-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=739c7fbd20660...83f (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/56/c9c...e91/deltalake-0.1.4-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=f1b...722f4af56533a (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dd/8e/7a2...75c/deltalake-0.1.4-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=d...750eaac478d131d (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c6/a5/2e3...4a2/deltalake-0.1.4-cp37-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=edb7f89ba1720...b84 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a9/d1/c26...6e5/deltalake-0.1.4-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=a789...9dca68e7a48b (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/86/92/f47...bb2/deltalake-0.1.4-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=7c...4653eb9297b946 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/da/53/f87...383/deltalake-0.1.4-cp38-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=6c505faf63e21...b54 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/39/40c...cd0/deltalake-0.1.4-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=5c5c...f4ef9d7828de (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/95/993...580/deltalake-0.1.4-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=27...c4225d0d10ada3 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0a/ec/b04...90d/deltalake-0.1.4-cp39-none-win_amd64.whl#sha256=0b8ab63759185...efc (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/ad/7b3...db3/deltalake-0.2.0-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=2413...5731f53951b7 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f9/61/d10...142/deltalake-0.2.0-cp36-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=1b...3044645ceb052d (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a6/15/44c...840/deltalake-0.2.0-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl#sha256=d37b60edc9251...f99 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/27/08/b0f...9cf/deltalake-0.2.1-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=b662...0a98307c1c96 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/10/15/56e...3ff/deltalake-0.2.1-cp36-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=98...c4bf01497c4ef3 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d3/3b/8ab...254/deltalake-0.2.1-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl#sha256=f35ddf1955ebd...6cb (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ed/aa/03a...3c4/deltalake-0.3.0-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=b9ff...5f680839052b (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d2/a9/e05...eb0/deltalake-0.3.0-cp36-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=3a...ada4a4020c819c (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/44/2f/ce8...fcd/deltalake-0.3.0-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl#sha256=c1f3543904428...308 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1f/45/904...4df/deltalake-0.4.0-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=6931...2373131ed630 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/57/bad...712/deltalake-0.4.0-cp36-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=65...2b189b6a324b4d (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/04/d6/10b...86d/deltalake-0.4.0-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl#sha256=c4acbcd263fc4...e72 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2f/2a/e5c...c47/deltalake-0.4.1-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=4754...3ad294f14a66 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/20/301...02b/deltalake-0.4.1-cp36-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=cb...421e7b3a375df9 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cc/d9/778...0fc/deltalake-0.4.1-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl#sha256=bce5c6c74adc3...ae3 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/c6/a47...dca/deltalake-0.4.2-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=f9f0...a98fcbab7b05 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/64/012...27c/deltalake-0.4.2-cp36-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=c7...9a13d745225d7a (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/96/191...88a/deltalake-0.4.3-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=e329...41979718285b (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c0/22/fb4...e86/deltalake-0.4.3-cp36-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=c5...87282167da5747 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6c/04/2bc...697/deltalake-0.4.3-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl#sha256=b00c98ad5a6bc...cb1 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/56/c49...e15/deltalake-0.4.4-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=f3cb...4a2a55b7943d (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7f/60/669...95b/deltalake-0.4.4-cp36-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=41...5e2edb50436f15 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7d/5a/faf...a21/deltalake-0.4.4-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl#sha256=c8e895bec9660...90a (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/db/36/557...edf/deltalake-0.4.5-cp36-abi3-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl#sha256=464a...e0165a9c8217 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/47/fb4...e54/deltalake-0.4.5-cp36-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=c8...46e793f6a2661b (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/75/28/525...dd6/deltalake-0.4.5-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl#sha256=0eff9824518d4...b53 (from https://pypi.org/simple/deltalake/); it is not compatible with this Python
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement deltalake (from versions: )
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for deltalake
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 346, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 514, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
pip.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for deltalake
[ec2-user@ip-10-142-224-101 ~]$
```

Comment: run the pip command with `-v` flag to get verbose output: `pip3 -v install deltalake`, and put the log here

Comment: Hi Alex, just added the verbose mode logs.

Comment: hmm, strange... I don't have AWS linux to try myself